# Creating dynamic link with ui-sref inserting with highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm trying to create a category xAxis that acts as links to other areas of the app. I want to avoid using href because that will reload everything. I have the core of the problem down, I think.

```
labels: {
    formatter: function () {
        let newvar = $compile(`<a class="link">${this.value} - ${vm.tableData.contentMain[this.pos].bothNeeded} - ${vm.tableData.contentMain[this.pos].percentageCompleted}</a> - `)($scope)

        return angular.element(newvar[0]);
    },
    useHTML: true
}
```

My problem is that [object Object] shows on the page instead of the link. I believe I need to compile in order to get the ui-sref to work, which is why it is there. Any help creating these dynamic links greatly appreciated!

I am running Angular 1.6 in case that matters

**UPDATE**

Hopefully I am misunderstanding how $compile works. Here is a bad, non-working example OUTSIDE of highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/31241/

Comment: Have you tried just returning newvar[0]?

Comment: Yeah, I've also tried something simpler like let newvar = $compile(`<div>test</div>`)($scope)

and I still get object Object

Comment: It seems like the formatter only likes strings, but I need it to compile to the href

Comment: Can you post demo fiddle?

Comment: Sure, I might be missing something surrounding $compile since I had a similar issue doing an even simpler example

Comment: As you noticed, `formatter` accepts only strings, not HTML elements. How about returning strings and using [`custom-events`](https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) plugin for Highcharts?

Answer (score 2):

From HighCharts Docs `formatter` returns String. So you have nothing to do with it. `$compile` generated DOM element that has been regestered to digest cycle. So its not out case.

However you can generate string something like:

```
 formatter: function () {
       return '<div style="width:70px" onclick="alert(\''+this.value+'\')">'+$scope.someValues[this.value]+'</div>';       
    },
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xj1pabvv/)

> I want to avoid using href  ...

you can build custom href by modifieng it based on `this.vaue`

---

As a side note:

When you print in DOM `$compile`d object, you get something like: `{"0":{"ng-1505336047666":6},"length":1}` where `0` is id of `$scope` and `1505336047666` element id that regenerates each build

Comment: Is there a way to use the element (el) without appending it? Such as setting it to $scope.el and then using {{el}}? I tried something similar with no success. Since highcharts expects a return value from the formatter, I think that's the issue.

Comment: @Organiccat I cannot help you with out demo: try to update this one: http://jsfiddle.net/yvspm5zd/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/694wa8ym/3/

Simpler example trying to avoid .append

Comment: Because I can't compile, that means the ui-sref won't work. The above works for simpler strings, but the compile is necessary to get the ui-sref bound properly.

Comment: @Organiccat you must return string, so you can take state and build final URL

Comment: Something simple like <a class="link" ui-sref="app.goHere({id:2})"> doesn't work unfortunately as a string because of the missing compile tying it to app scope

Comment: Can you make it a regular function instead of tying it to app so you could use it without the angular compile?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if you provide a cloneAttachFn and then assign the result to the scope you can get it to do what you're looking for.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
  {{newthing}}
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.link = $compile(`<div>Test</div>`)(
      $scope, 
      function(clonedElement, scope) { 
        console.log(clonedElement[0]); 
        $scope.newthing = clonedElement[0].outerText;
      }
    );
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/31285/